# VXML check which audio is playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, vxml

Is there anyway in javascript for checking which vxml audio element is currently playing similar to HTML audio element ? or whether audio playing has ended or started ?

Answer (score 0):

If you end your audio list with a form and your VoiceXML browser supports it, you can use the [mark feature](https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/#sec-mark) to accomplish what you want.  However, it is messy as it isn't usually implemented and there isn't a standard way to get the results.  As I read it, you only get the time offset, not the specific clip, so then you are forced into embedding your file lengths into your code to interpret what file was playing.  I've never found it practical to use this feature.

Given those limitations, you are back to the answer suggested in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822994/vxml-audio-file-playing-status/65837975#65837975).  Insert forms between the files with very short timeouts.

Comment: If there is a mark before every single audio tag and one after the last, the markname should tell you which audio tag is playing without needing to know the time.  The time is only needed if you want to know how much of the most recent audio was played.  Or do I have that wrong?